# Error Undefined offset

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want insert following checkbox in a row from database table, but have error, how is fix it? (I can not change 5 in name checkbox)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_units_a[5][]" value="tv">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_units_a[5][]" value="radio">

$name_un = $this -> input -> post('name_units_a');
$service_un = $this -> input -> post('checkbox_units_a');
$data3 = array();
foreach($name_un as $idx => $name) {
    $data3[] = array(
    'name_un' => $name_un[$idx],
    'service_un' => json_encode($service_un[$idx]), ); //This is line 210
};
$this -> db -> insert_batch('hotel_units', $data3);
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message:
>   Undefined offset: 0
>  Filename: residence.php
>  Line Number:
>   210

My output in `var_dump` from `$name_un`:

```
array(1) {
    [0] = > string(6)"accessories"
}
```

My output in `var_dump` from `$service_un`:

```
array(1) {
    [5] = > array(2) {
        [0] = > string(15)"tv" [1] = > string(12)"radio"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to print the $service_un array: `print_r($service_un);` ?

Comment: You need to improve your **written English**, it is VERY difficult to understand your questions.

Comment: Please see my update(output vardump) in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says your offset is equal `0` propably your `$idx == 0` and `$service_un[$idx] == null` ;)

**EDIT**

As I thought `$idx == 0` is causing undefined offset 0 in `json_encode` try to reindex your `$service_un` array (if you cannot change the `5` in HTML) to make it start with `0` example:

```
$service_un = array_values ( $service_un ); // reindexing array
```

it will look like:

```
array(1) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(2) "tv"
    [1] => string(5) "radio"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and please print `var_dump($name_un)`

Comment: Please see my post for `var_dump($name_un)`

Answer (score 0):

`$service_un` have only one offset, and it's five(5), So 0 is undefined here.